# Is it possible to extract and/or set users' birthday with a PowerShell script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, microsoft-graph, delve

I've been doing some investigating and apparently a user's birthday date (the one that shows up on Delve) is not stored in a property inside the user's own office365 account object.

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script in Azure where I can update a user's birthday with a value that is currently in a SharePoint list. As of right now if I could find out how to even set the birthday property hard-coded, that would be some progress.

Get-MsolUser and Set-Msoluser don't work because as I stated previously the birthday date isn't there for some reason, but I can retrieve a user's birthday utilizing Microsoft Graph and sending a GET request to this URL of the API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/birthday`.

The response of that request is what I would like to be able to automatically set, but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Comment: I believe I found the answer to my question here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http will update if it works

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.sptrenches.com/2015/05/write-and-get-user-profile-properties-the-scripts.html)? Do you want to perform this using PowerShell or Microsoft Graph?

Comment: I saw that but didn't follow through because I didn't think that Delve and SP user details would be connected, I was only looking for office365 user properties.

Comment: And I want to perform it with powershell, but if cmdlet didn't exist I was considering creating a script to invoke a rest method and patch the birthday dates that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally worked. Here's the code to change one single user's birthday date (...where $creds name is the name of a credential created on the azure automation account used to run the script, with full sharepoint admin privileges given on the admin site (the same site used as url)):

````
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxxx-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credentials $creds

Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account 'xx.xxxx@xxx.com' -PropertyName "SPS-Birthday" -Value "01/14/2020"```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can set the birth date using [Set-PnPUserProfileProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpuserprofileproperty) in PnP PowerShell.

For Example:

```
Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account 'user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com' -PropertyName "SPS-Birthday" -Value "01/14/2020"
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

I tried running the graph query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/birthday`. This also returns the same birth date:

[image]

**Update Birth date using Microsoft Graph**:

Method: PATCH

Endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}
```

Request body:

```
{
    "birthday":"2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would this update the Delve "birthday" property as well?

Comment: Yes it will. Check the command I used and the output in updated answer.

Comment: This sets the value to the UPSA which isn't a Graph query, what the OP was asking about. UPSA will be going away so I'd suggest the Graph route.

Comment: This is one-time thing that I need to run in order to update our employees' birthday dates @TrevorSeward, do you recon the graph approach is better? One problem I found is that my account doesn't have access to change other people's properties. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: I tried running the graph query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/birthday`. This also returns the same birth date as I set using PnP PowerShell. see updated answer. To update the user profile properties of other users, you will need administrator permissions.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thank you for the answer. I am attempting the script method first, but running into some problems. The account I'm using to create and run the script on Azure is a full-admin on our sharepoint, yet I still get a 401 - not authorized when attempting to change the birthday date of a coworker. Here's the code:
`Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxxx.sharepoint.com -CurrentCredentials

Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account 'xxxxx@xxxx.com' -PropertyName "SPS-Birthday" -Value "01/14/2020"`

Comment: Try using this: `Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxxx-admin.sharepoint.com/ -UseWebLogin`